# word2vec: Is there any implementation in java to work with phrases?

Tags: java, machine-learning, word2vec

I would like to ask if you know any implementation of word2vec in java being able to work with phrases and not just single words.

The existing java implementation from http://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec.html works only with single words.

This one is written in C and it is archived: https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/

Comment: Maybe it works with a custom Tokenizer?

Comment: How about [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) or [Medallia](https://github.com/medallia/Word2VecJava)?

Comment: Actually, the Deeplearning4j version works with phrases. It has doc2vec and GloVe. Here's an example: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-0.4-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/paragraphvectors/ParagraphVectorsClassifierExample.java